# Android: ListView, min scroll position

Tags: android

I have 10 items in ListView.
Sometimes I dont want user to be able to see first list item.
So Second one should be like first one.

How to prevent user to scroll to the first item ?
Or maybe there is better solutions or ready API to do that ?

P.S: HeaderView not works for me

Comment: What is the reason for downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to simply remove (temporarily) the item from your List (or whichever collection you are using), and then re-fill the ListView with:

```
listView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Another thing you could do is return an empty view when your 'position == 0' so the first item would not be displayed you'd also have to call the 'notifyDataSetChanged()' method here when the condition would change.

Comment: Why is this the "best solution"?

Comment: Simple, effective, hard to break your code with it. I also dont see any other simple way of doing it. Using listeners and such is too complex for something as simple as this imho.

Comment: Yes it's simple, yes it's effective. However you will recall getView for all visible views unnecessarily. And if you're downloading images on your Adapter then this is not the "best solution". By far.

Answer (score 1):

This code will block the first item from being seen by selecting the second item on the list.

```
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            if (i == 0)
                absListView.setSelection(1);
        }
    });
```